# How can I change the variation printed in the main function?

Tags: python

```
number=[]
def reverseList3(list):
        for i in list[::-1] :
            if i!= max(list) :
                number.append(i)
        return(number)

def main():
    list = [20,60,40,10,50]
    print(list)
main()
```

list has to be `[50,10,40,20]` which is same as `reverseList3(list)`, but it keeps printing `[20,60,40,10,50]`

how can I change list without touching the main function?

The language is Python

Comment: You don't modify `lst` how could you expecct if to be different ? You don't even call any method

Comment: The only thing your code does is : printing  a list, so YES it keeps printing the same

Comment: Oh I see thank you I missed the 'lst=number' line but it still doesn't work

Comment: Yu should pass that list to first function and return the list  as per condition

Comment: If you don't modify `main` at all, it won't work, that the entrypoint of the code

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't want to change or touch the main function?

Comment: The professor told me not to change it. Actually that one is my assignment

Comment: You call ONE method that does nothing and you CAN'T change it : how could expect the code to do something else, tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function to get expected output and pass the list when you call the function

```
number=[]
def reverseList3(lst):
    for i in lst[::-1] :
        if i!= max(lst) :
            number.append(i)
    return(number)

def main():
    lst = [20,60,40,10,50]
return lst 

lst=main() # calling main function
print(reverseList3(lst))
```

Comment: thanks a lot but I cannot even add a line in `main` that's why I'm having trouble with this one :(

Comment: so can you return anything from main function??

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand what do you mean by can I return anything from main function? I can fix anything if it's not the main function

Answer (score 0):

Replacing print by return would work.

```
number=[]

def reverseList3(list):
        for i in list[::-1] :
            if i!= max(list) :
                number.append(i)
        return(number)

def main():
    list = [20,60,40,10,50]
    return list

print(reverseList3(main()))
```

Comment: cannot revise the `main` even for a little bit.. sorry:(